# How can I use input redirection AND manual input in an interactive program?

Tags: bash, input, io-redirection

I have an executable of a program, written in Fortran that needs interactive input, for example 20 inputs. What I want, is to give the first 19 inputs through input redirection but the last one from my keyboard. The reason is because when I run the program I get a message

```
file list_wall.dat written - modify it to group walls
modify wallList.dat (add flag type) - enter 1 when ready
```

So before I press 1, I need to modify a file manually and then press 1 manually. I have tried to run it like this

```
./my_interactive_program < input.in
```

where I have the first 19 lines written in this input.in file.
However, when it reaches the last line I get a message like this:

```
$forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit -4, file stdin
```

So, instead of waiting for my input from the keyboard, it detects the end of the file and the program crashes.
Can I do something about it?

Comment: I guess reading the input in Bash and then piping both to your program is not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can ask the user for the 20th input up front:

```
read -p "input 20: " inp
{ cat input.in; echo "$inp"; } | ./my_interactive_program
```

Otherwise, `expect` is a sledgehammer you can employ:

```
expect <<'END'
spawn ./my_interactive_program
set fh [open input.in r]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    send -- "$line\r"
}
close $fh
interact
END
```

Comment: I have tried everything that was mentioned here but nothing worked. "Expect" seemed promising but it was not available. I installed it and tried to run the above mentioned piece of code but it doesn't seem to start working... It only prints:     "spawn ./my_interactive_program"     . I don't know what is wrong. I also tried to only initiate the program without any input but this didn't work either. Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make a .sh file that outputs all the inputs (are you still with me? :), asks for user input and then outputs that as well:

```
echo hello
echo world
read input
echo $input
```

Then run that .sh file and pipe the output through your fortran program.

Comment: Thank you but I don't think this will help. I have modified the original question so maybe it is clearer now what I want to do and why I need it.

Comment: If you replace the first two echos by 'cat input.in' you will get what you need, I think.

Answer (score 0):

A flexible tool to automate interactive programs is [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/). You can use it to feed arbitrary input (say, read from a file and counting the lines) to your fortran program. Once you get to the prompt you issue the command `interact` and expect passes control to the terminal's stdin.

Comment: I have tried to use the piece of code that was suggested above but I have an issue again. When I  run this from the command line in a terminal, everything runs fine. However, when I add this to bash script, it does not run... Please note, that I do not include the part " <<'END' " because it does not work.